# Can a private key in the SecureEnclave be unlocked with a local authentication context?

Tags: ios, security, pki

I am generating my key pairs inside the SE and want them to be protected with user-presence. At the same time, I want to protect access to my App with a user password.

I can do either but two problems remain:

1) protecting the key that is ultimately used in a TLS handshake seems to time out if it needs to be authenticated during the handshake. This leaves only protection with a pre-authenticated context as an option.

2) protecting the perimeter of the app (for data on rest) is possible with application password or fingerprint but not both (the password as a fallback just like with the device passcode).

Finally, I would like to combine both: require knowledge or fingerprint to enter the App and at the same time unlock the private key in the enclave. I also want to enforce an automatic (read: no userland code) timeout on the context.

Most of this things seem not to be possible but I post here to maybe get some creative ideas on workarounds or even someone who knows how to do some of the functions stated.

Any help welcome.

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I think I described it well.